# How to make or simulate perspiration?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I want to know if it's possible to simulate perspiration on a surface in cycles such as in the following images:

[image: human perspiration]

[image: simulated orange perspiration]

If so what techniques should be used?

Comment: Usually this is done with a particle system.  Are you specifically looking for a solution using just material shaders or are you open to a solution using particles?

Comment: Are we talking about animation or still images? I'll suggest to have a look at http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-rainy-window/ tutorial, if you hadn't already.

Comment: @PGmath :  I'm open to both options.

Comment: @Carlo I'm talking about still images but I wouldn't mind learning about the animation method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a separate layer create an object that will have the shape of your droplets, and give it the material you need.

[image]

Then on the main object add a particle system with start and end on frame 1, no physics and using the drop object as the render object.

[image]

Comment: How about simulating trails that would come along with? I remember a technique that was demonstrated by Blender Guru, but he did it in the internal render at the time, not cycles.

Comment: ten you'll have to enable Physics, so that they flow... Please include what you need as part of the question...

Comment: I had just remembered that he used a uv unwrapped image as a factor in determining which part of the surface is completely glossy and and which is not. I believe that I know to do it that method since I have done it with eye reflections. Thank you for the particle suggestion though.

Comment: @cegaton great answer. Can the position or rotation of particles be randomized?

Comment: @fabriced yes, use the random, rotation and size control for the particles