# how to create real Condensation on glass with cycles

Tags: particles

how to create the condensation like image below, its really good and particle looks so neatly arranged and theres no overlapping particles. Thanks[image]

Comment: you could try this addon: https://github.com/BorisTheBrave/blue-noise-particles

Comment: I already installed the blue noise, but after i install adds-on, the blender 2.79 cant read the adds-on blue noise, report error. do u have any solution for this??

Comment: Have you tried with a Particle System / Hair? What problem did you meet? You should not see overlapping particles if there are as separated

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57485/how-to-make-or-simulate-perspiration

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137541/how-can-i-make-drops-of-fluid-hang-from-a-surface

Comment: i have tried with particle hair, and it seem looks good, but unfortunately, always have overlapping on the particles...not at all but mostly, so i have tried to link metaball with particles systems hair, but it takes more times then usually.